# Javascript multiple callbacks

Tags: javascript, html

I am using this [plugin](http://abpetkov.github.io/powerange/) to display 2 price range sliders on my website. The problem is that when i add a second range slider the first one doesn't work anymore.

The js code i use is:

```
// Range 1
var clbk = document.querySelector('.value1');
var initClbk = new Powerange(clbk, { callback: displayValue, start: 20 });
function displayValue() {
  document.getElementById('slider1').innerHTML = clbk.value;
}

// Range 2
var clbk = document.querySelector('.value2');
var initClbk = new Powerange(clbk, { callback: displayValue, start: 40 });
function displayValue() {
  document.getElementById('slider2').innerHTML = clbk.value;
}
```

I also uploaded here a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h3fyupjm/2/) example.

What i am doing wrong ?

Comment: You are using the same function name twice.... rename the second `displayValue` to `displayValue2`

Comment: modified fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/pe49hnzu/

Comment: There are multiple issues in the code - https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9c2pew9b/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the right answer: Your problem is you calling same function, same variables, and thats a big error, because are diferent, check this fiddle the correction ;)

HTML

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">
 <input type="text" class="value1" />
 <label class="display-box-label"> Value1:</label>
 <div id="slider1" class="display-box"></div>
</div>

<div class="slider-wrapper">
 <input type="text" class="value2" />
 <label class="display-box-label"> Value2:</label>
 <div id="slider2" class="display-box"></div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
// Range 1
var clbk1 = document.querySelector('.value1');
var initClbk1 = new Powerange(clbk1, { callback: displayValue1, start: 20 });
function displayValue1() {
  document.getElementById('slider1').innerHTML = clbk1.value;
}

// Range 2
var clbk2 = document.querySelector('.value2');
var initClbk2 = new Powerange(clbk2, { callback: displayValue2, start: 40 });
function displayValue2() {
  document.getElementById('slider2').innerHTML = clbk2.value;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h3fyupjm/10/

Answer (score 0):

Two things, at first check your ids in code, there is no `slider1` id

Second, you overwrite function `displayValue`. You can't have two functions with the same name

Check working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/h3fyupjm/9/

Comment: Thanks for your help but even in your fiddle update the first slider doesnt work. Just try to slide it.

Comment: @Marsel because you re-used literally all your variable names. The first label is showing the value of the second slider.